# DisplayPort Not Detected: Ubuntu 16.10 and Dell Optiplex 3020

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, intel-graphics, displayport

I'm unsuccessfully trying to setup two display monitors in Dell OptiPlex 3020 with Ubuntu 16.10.

My main display is at VGA output and second and undetected is at DisplayPort.

**Following goes some configurations details:**

$ uname -a

```
Linux desa475 4.8.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 21 17:24:18 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

$ lsmod | grep video

```
video                  40960  2 dell_wmi,i915
```

$ xrandr -q

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

(**DP-1 is always disconnected**)

$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

$ ll /etc/X11

```
total 84
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 out 12 16:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 142 root root 12288 jan 24 19:38 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 out 12 16:30 app-defaults/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    15 out 12 16:30 default-display-manager
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 out 12 16:28 fonts/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 17394 set 27 14:03 rgb.txt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 jan 17 15:07 xinit/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 mai 24  2016 xkb/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   709 set 27 14:03 Xreset*
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 out 12 16:28 Xreset.d/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 out 12 16:28 Xresources/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  3730 set 27 14:08 Xsession*
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 jan 17 17:06 Xsession.d/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   265 set 27 14:03 Xsession.options
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 out 12 16:30 xsm/
```

**About my attempts:**

1. Firstly, I've checked my hardware: so I've found that my BIOS version was kind of old (A03) and I did an upgrade to A14 as advised [here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN290618/EN). After that a new video option apeared at BIOS menu where I could selected between "Auto" and "Intel HD graphics". None of than worked.
2. I've also tried to work with cvt and xrandr to add a new mode and force the output but I always get ""xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed";
3. I've also up to date versions os nvidia and intel graphics;
4. I've also tested one monitor only on DisplayPort, but it doesn't work either.

I really can't say where the issue is: hardware, driver, configuration or OS.

I do really appreciate any ideas in this matter.

**Update**

I also found [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/539289-dell-optiplex-3020-getting-multiple-monitors-to-work) thread, which is a bit confusing, but it seems to me that onboard VGA and DP should be supported.

Comment: Did you try DP to HDMI? I am trying to troubleshooting the display for DP port as well. I am using a cable of DP-HDMI and it doesn't work.

Comment: @jz.Wang no. I didnt. My displays are lacking of HDMI input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as soon as I posted the questions I've found the solution.

I was using an adaptor DP to VGA which is not supported!

Check [Dell Knowledge Base: Unable To Configure Dual Monitors](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN293001) for more info.

In the end I've changed it to DVI which was supported by my monitor as well and it works instantly.